# ¿Como fusionar dos columnas y separar otras dos en mysql?

Tags: mysql

estoy tratando de separar dos columnas y juntar dos tambien, pero son diferentes, la idea es juntas dos queries:
Querie 1:

```
SELECT 
    codcta, 
    sum(monmn) as Positivo 
 FROM home_diario
 WHERE monmn > 0 AND fecasi LIKE "%-01-%"
 GROUP BY codcta
 ORDER BY codcta;
```

Querie 2:

```
SELECT 
    codcta, 
    sum(monmn) as Negativo 
 FROM home_diario
 WHERE monmn < 0 AND fecasi LIKE "%-01-%"
 GROUP BY codcta
 ORDER BY codcta;
```

Resultado de Querie 1:

```
| codcta   | Positivo           |
+----------+--------------------+
| 10100100 |          238484.56 |
| 10100200 |              691.6 |
| 10100300 | 1182.6999999999998 |
| 10100400 |             139.44 |
| 10100500 |          203212.21 |
```

Resultado de Querie 2:

```
+----------+---------------------+
| codcta   | Negativo            |
+----------+---------------------+
| 10100100 | -246743.78000000003 |
| 10100200 |            -1109.99 |
| 10100300 | -1182.6999999999998 |
| 10100400 |             -139.44 |
```

Y deseo que se ponga asi:

```
| codcta   | Positivo           | Negativo           |
+----------+--------------------+--------------------+
| 10100100 |          238484.56 | -246743.78000000003|
| 10100200 |              691.6 | -1109.99           |
| 10100300 | 1182.6999999999998 | -1182.6999999999998|
| 10100400 |             139.44 | -139.44            |
| 10100500 |         203212.21  |  0                 |
```

He tratado con UNION y UNION ALL, pero me da un resultado en una sola columna,
y duplica la columna "codcta":

```
|codcta   | Posit_Negativ
|10100100 |238484.56
|10100100 |246743.78
```

Tambien he intentado con FULL JOIN, sin exito alguno.
Eso esto todo, muchas gracias.
Querie sin exito con full Join:

```
-- debe_01 es una view de la querie 1 //create view debe_01 as (querie1)
-- haber_01 es una view de la querie 2 //create view haber_01 as (querie2)

SELECT * FROM debe_01 
FULL JOIN 
(
SELECT * FROM haber_01
) as table3
ON table3.codcta = debe_01.codcta;
```

Pero si cambio a LEFT, o RIGHT , en la anterior querie, si funciona, pero solo muestra una parte comun de la izquierda o derecha,pero con FULL no funciona, error que me sale es:

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'debe_01.codcta' in 'on clause'
```

Nota: El numero de fila de la querie 1 es mas grande que el numero de filas de la querie 2, asi que cuando hago el LEFT o RIGHT JOIN, me sale null a veces, en los:

```
USE sisinfo;

SELECT table3.codcta,debe_01.DEBE,table3.HABER
FROM debe_01 
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT * FROM sisinfo.haber_01 ) 
as 
table3 ON table3.codcta = debe_01.codcta;
```

[image: Querie con LEFT JOIN]

Comment: Puedes decirnos en como quedo tu inner join para saber en que te falla?

Comment: Esto se puede hacer con un join, y tambien se puede hacer todo en una sola query.... mostra tu join porfa...

Comment: ok, estoy editando la pregunta...

Comment: No se que error me sale con full, la verdad no se explicar por que pasa eso, supongo que es por que no tiene alias, lo intente, y tampoco funciona

Comment: y que se supone que son las tablas debe y haber_

Comment: hola @gbianchi debe es "positivo", y haber es "negativo"

Comment: Ordena tu pregunta.. no se que son las tablas debe y haber... si no mostras como se hicieron y que tienen, dificil ayudarte...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes intentar lo siguiente

```
SELECT 
    h1.codcta, 
    sum(IFNULL(h2.monmn,0)) as Positivo,
    sum(IFNULL(h3.monmn,0)) as Negativo 
 FROM home_diario h1
 LEFT JOIN home_diario h2 ON h1.codcta = h2.codcta AND h2.monmn > 0
 LEFT JOIN home_diario h3 ON h1.codcta = h3.codcta AND h3.monmn < 0
 WHERE h1.fecasi LIKE "%-01-%"
 GROUP BY h1.codcta
 ORDER BY h1.codcta;
```

Comment: Hola, he intentado lo que me dices, pero me sale : running...., luego Error Code: 2013 Lost connection to mysql server.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563619/error-code-2013-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query intenta con la respuesta de ese post

Comment: Cambie el request Time Out a 6000, y no funciona hasta ahora, se queda esperando en running, algo de tiempo, y me sal el mismo error, el problema radica en que el ciclo de espera solo es mas largo. Creo hay algo mal en mi codigo, pero no se porque el full join(), no me funciona, me dice "expected EOF ; ", pero no consigo encontrar el error.

Comment: Hola @R.Nuñez Creo que las filas son demasiado largas es por eso que trate de  hacerlas en VIEW's.

Comment: Pues mas bien creo estan mal echa tu consulta por que estas intentando unir lo mas seguro que strings, por eso tarda tanto en realizar el query, ya que no se han de estar uniendo por una llave primaria

Comment: Tienes masomenos razon, son unos 50000 datos, y los quiero dividir por fecasi, luego dividirlos con haber y debe, pero gracias por tu respuesta, tengo la idea de exportar individualemente en csv's la querie1 y queri2, con el mismo numero de filas(con algunos ceros en codcta), no sabia de la funcion ifnull(), gracias.